Screen not popping to original screen
I have implemented a separate screen to show the error message. In the init state of the error screen, I have implemented a timer so that it pops back to the original login screen after 3 seconds of showing the error. However, after showing the screen for 3 seconds, I get a black screen, and not the original login screen. Can someone explain why? Is there a better way to do it?
Codes:
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<AuthCubit, AuthState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is AuthSuccess) {
          return buildSuccessScreen(state);
        } else if (state is AuthError) {
          return ErrorScreen(state.message);
        } else if (state is AuthPrompt) {
          return _LoginForm(buildSuccessScreen);
        } else {
          return const Scaffold(
            body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }



class ErrorScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ErrorScreen(this.error, {super.key});

  final String error;

  @override
  State<ErrorScreen> createState() => _ErrorScreenState();
}

class _ErrorScreenState extends State<ErrorScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    Timer(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {
      Navigator.pop(context);
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      body: Center(
          child: Text(
        widget.error,
        style: const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontSize: 20,
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}


Why do you want to push to a new screen in order to show the error?

I just want the error message not to show after 3 seconds. I used a new screen and a timer in the new screen. What is the alternative?

In general, if you want to show an error for X amount of time, then you should implement a snackbar. Snackbars are meant to be used for success, error, and other states and they are dismissed automatically after Y amount of time. Check this https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/design/snackbars#interactive-example

Looking at the code, how do I inject a snackbar in there. Its expecting a widget to be returned for each states. How can I put a snackbar instead?

In BLoC architecture, Snackbars and Navigation is usually handled either in BlocListeners or in button presses. For example, you can wrap your widget with a bloc listener using AuthCubit and using parameter listenWhen you can order the listener to trigger when your state changes from X state to Error State. Then inside the listener parameter you can write the code that displays the Snackbar.

Do you have a code, if possible?

Are you doing any Navigator.of(context).push? If not maybe you should update your AuthCubit's state after 3 seconds so your build method returns the correct widget (I believe _LoginForm(buildSuccessScreen))

I tried push first instead of pop. I get the original screen by using that, but no longer get the functionalities in the login screen. (no longer able to login).

I think you miss-understood what I asked. In order for you to use Navigator.of(context).pop you need to have used Navigator.of(context).push before that. If you didn't push any page, then you cannot pop anything

Since it seems you are not pushing any page before, you might want to change your AuthState to AuthPrompt after the 3 seconds wait

How do I do that?

If you mean changing your AuthState to AuthPrompt you need to look at AuthCubit and modify it correctly so its state is AuthPrompt. I cannot help you more without you sharing the code of AuthCubit and AuthState

You are getting a black screen because you are actually not pushing anything on the navigation stack and simply just replacing screen based on your AuthState and then you are trying to pop the only screen available in navigation stack, thus you are seeing a blank screen.
Your code:
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<AuthCubit, AuthState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is AuthSuccess) {
          return buildSuccessScreen(state);
        } else if (state is AuthError) {
          return ErrorScreen(state.message);
        } else if (state is AuthPrompt) {
          return _LoginForm(buildSuccessScreen);
        } else {
          return const Scaffold(
            body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }

Solution:
Please find implementation below:
class ExamplePagePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const ExamplePagePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ExampleCubit, ExampleCubitState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        if (state is AuthSuccess) {
          return buildSuccessScreen(state);
        } else if (state is AuthError) {
          context.read<ExampleCubit>().replaceErrorScreen();
          return ErrorScreen(state.message);
        } else if (state is AuthPrompt) {
          return _LoginForm(buildSuccessScreen);
        } else {
          return const Scaffold(
            body: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}

class ExampleCubit extends Cubit<ExampleCubitState> {
  ExampleCubit() : super(ExampleCubitInitial());

  Timer? timer;

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    timer?.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }

  void replaceErrorScreen() {
    timer = Timer(
      const Duration(seconds: 3),
      () {
        emit(ExampleCubitInitial());
      },
    );
  }
}

@immutable
sealed class ExampleCubitState {}

final class ExampleCubitInitial extends ExampleCubitState {}

final class AuthSuccess extends ExampleCubitState {}

final class AuthError extends ExampleCubitState {}

final class AuthPrompt extends ExampleCubitState {}

If you find this useful, Kindly upvote this answer

Yes, please. I would love to see it.

I post here the BlocListener approach cause it doesnt fit in the comment. If that helped you please accept this as an answer.
BlocListener<AuthCubit, AuthState>(
  listenWhen: (previousState, state) {
    // return true/false to determine whether or not
    // to call listener with state
    return previousState != state && state is AuthError;

  },
  listener: (context, state) {
    // do stuff here based on BlocA's state
   final snackBar = SnackBar(
            content: const Text('Yay! A SnackBar!'),
            action: SnackBarAction(
              label: 'Undo',
              onPressed: () {
                // Some code to undo the change.
              },
            ),
          );

          // Find the ScaffoldMessenger in the widget tree
          // and use it to show a SnackBar.
          ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  },
  child: const YourWidget(),
);

